# How do I have an over 33,000 change in reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

I have got to hear the story behind this...bug? So confused right now. What happened?

[Weekly ranking site](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2022-06-26/14148586#14148586)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change is compared with the previous week's rank.
Your previous week rank is #34132 and this week's rank is #324, so the change is +33808 in the rank and not in the reputation.